# Evaluating sympy equation as decimal (inside sympy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I have a sympy equation that gives me:

```
>>> ans0=solve([c_eq1, c_eq2, v_eq1, v_eq2, v_eq3],[a, b, c, d, e])
>>> ans0
{a: 9/796, b: 27/3980, c: 9/1990, d: 5/796, e: 1/199}
```

Is there a way to get this answer in decimal without converting it to a float (outside sympy), for example with:

```
dict((var,float(value)) for var, value in ans0.items())
{a: 0.011306532663316583, b: 0.0067839195979899495, c: 0.004522613065326633, d: 0.00628140703517588, e: 0.005025125628140704}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question means which sympy function to use instead of `float`, you can use `N`

```
>>> from sympy import N
>>> dict((var, N(value)) for var, value in ans0.items())
```